# One Extra line is added when using mutt for .csv file

Tags: python, mutt

I am using python 3 and this is my code

```
   with open(f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)}.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
```

When I import file from my server to local(Macbook) it shows files in correct format.

when sending email using `mutt` command, it is adding extra line between each row.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This worked for me: This removed extra lines from output .csv:     '''with open(f"RMA{datetime.datetime.now().strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)}.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')'''

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me: This removed extra lines from output .csv:

```
open(f"RMA{datetime.datetime.now().strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)}.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
```